# how to store XML tags and retrieve data

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am having a hard time to understand this code, can anyone help me with this? 
If I'm not wrong, **StrStaffInfo** is used to store the XML tags.

I wanted to know how the tags are stored in the XML file, and how to access those Tags?

```
<script runat="server">
Public StaffInfoXML as new xmlDocument

sub Page_Load(obj as object, e as eventargs)

    Dim StrStaffInfo, strConnXMLData, strConnStr, SpString as String
    Dim oStaffDAW as New DAWNET.DataAccess.XMLWrapper.DAW()
    Dim oConn as new ConnectionString.Access.DataBase.IO.ConnectionString

    ' Fetch the Connection String from Configuration File
    oConn.SetPath(MapPath(""))
    strConnStr = oConn.FetchConnectionString(strConnXMLData)


    SpString = "StaffInformationSelect '"& Decode(LOGONUSER.ToString) &"','"& Decode(CLIENTIP.ToString) &"','"& Decode(MACHINENAME.ToString) &"'"
    oStaffDAW.FetchXml(strConnStr, SpString, StrStaffInfo)

            StaffInfoXML.LoadXml(StrStaffInfo)



    if (StaffInfoXML.GetElementsByTagName("RECORD").Count = 0)
        Response.Redirect("Application.aspx")
        Response.End
    End if

end sub
```

Where is the TagName "record" stored? I want to include another Tag, and check a If condition.

Comment: This looks like it's written in [VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) and/or [ASP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which in and of itself is not HTML. It might _produce_ HTML, but it alone is not HTML.

Comment: Yeah ASP, do you have any idea how the Tag is stored?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP to be honest, but I added the ASP tag to your post so hopefully the people with the right knowledge will see it. :)

Comment: @jerdiggity - ASP (Classic ASP) does not have `Page_Load`.  This is ASP.NET, it's just not using the more traditional code-behind approach.

Comment: Oops... Well I really did (try to) add the ASP.NET tag -- not ASP. Sorry for the confusion. :/

Comment: @jerdiggity - No problem.  I thought it was Classic ASP at first glance as well.

Comment: @tim  Can you tell me a solution for my question?

Comment: See my answer below - if you need more information, can you supply more details of what it is you're trying to do?  Also, do you have a sample of the XML you can post (if you do, edit your question and add it there).

Answer (score 1):

Note a direct answer to your question, but `strStaffInfo` is a string with the XML, and it is being loaded into an `XmlDocument` (`StaffInfoXML`) with the following line:

```
StaffInfoXML.LoadXml(StrStaffInfo)
```

The tag `RECORD` is somewhere in the document tree.  `GetElementsByTagName` returns an `XmlNodeList` of all the tags (nodes) and their children that have the name "RECORD" in the document.

If you know the name of the element (tag) you're looking for, you can make another call to `GetElementsByName`, and then check the value(s) of that/those element(s) for your `If` condition.

I would also take a look at LINQ to XML (which is my preferred method for parsing XML).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with terminology. A tag is just text delimited by less-than and greater-than characters. An *element* has opening and closing tags, and may have additional content between the two. Elements are the important thing.

The code is calling `StaffInformationSelect`, which appears to be a stored procedure in your database that produces an XML result. Yes, `StrStaffInfo` should hold the result as a string containing XML.

The XML result is then loaded into the `StaffInfoXML` object, which is an instance of [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), the .NET XML DOM (Document Object Model) class.

Then it's looking to see if the XML document has any RECORD elements, and if there are none, redirecting to another page. If the document looked like this:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<RECORD></RECORD>
<RECORD></RECORD>
</root>`

the Count property would have a value of 2.

Apart from the `GetElementsByTagName` method you see in the existing code, check out [GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx), which will locate an element by its unique ID.

The tag name is defined by `StaffInformationSelect`. It might correspond to a table name in your database.

`GetElementsByTagName` will produce a collection of `XmlNode` objects, which you could iterate through. If you want to do complex searching for some elements in the document, check out [XPathDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx), or perhaps the new [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), which allows you to run LINQ queries on an XML document.

If you can attach a debugger to this code, set a breakpoint on the line that calls LoadXML, and you should see the XML document in the StrStaffInfo variable.